# How to implement UITableViewCell without UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to use the power of UITableViewCell like disclosure accessory, but I don't need the whole UITableView. Is this possible and appropriate to do so ? I don't see any delegate on UITableViewCell, so don't know where should I put code previously in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` any references or suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if im wrong but .. Why would you use a cell like that ? If you dont want to use the power of the UITableView you can just add a view and do all the stuff you do in your cell. And that would keep the Apple Standard too.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment.

Comment: which he can't do due to reputation

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a `UITableView` with one section and one row, and load that cell into it. This would be pretty easy to do and wouldn't run the risk of running afoul of the Apple review board.

Comment: So it doesn't has any way to implement stand alone UITableViewCell ? I know I can implement it the way you said, but I had UI issue if implemented it that way.

Comment: I can now achieve my UI with UITableView, but still want to know if this UITableViewCell approach usable, so I think I will leave this question open for a while.

Comment: I think this question has been left open long enough. ;)